# asp.net c# text box onclick empty if default text. Unchanged if not default text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I put a textbox control in my aspx page :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchCriteriaTextBox" runat="server" Text="Enter Search Criteria" Width="150px" ForeColor="GrayText" OnClick="this.value = ''; this.style.color = 'black'" OnBlur="javascript:changeText(this.id)" />
```

So the text box get empty on click. Keep whatever I type. But if I click outside of the text box and then click back to the text box to edit the text I typed, it is not working. It make the whole text box empty.

Basically I am trying to get similar functionality like if the search text box in this forum. By default the text is: "Search ASP.NET". I click to type something, the text box get empty. I type "Monir" and click outside of the box. It keep the text "Monir". I click back to edit the text, it keeps "Monir" so now I can add "like asp.net" So the text is now: "Monir like asp.net"

Any help please ??

Comment: Use 'TextBoxWatermarkExtender' of AJAX toolkit

Comment: Use HTML5 `placeholder` and fall back on JavaScript like [here](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" value="Enter Search Criteria" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"></asp:Textbox>
```

Comment: While this will work perfectly i have to also direct you to [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript#Unobtrusive_JavaScript_defined)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtSearchWaterMark" 
    runat="server" TargetControlID="SearchCriteriaTextBox" 
    WatermarkText="Enter Search Criteria..." />

<asp:TextBox ID="SearchCriteriaTextBox" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I used the answer that was provided by Kashif with a small edit. Instead of asp tag, I had to use ajax tag. Also, another side note,if you want this as a optional field and if you are extracting the text from the text box, the on blur/on focus method that was described in the first answer will pull the placeholder if the user does not input anything. The TextBoxWatermark does not though, so that is the one you want to use if the text box is a optional field.

Comment: You should format your answer in such a way that if @Kashif answer was deleted, your answer would stand alone (whilst mentioning his answer as a reference, like you did). Also, use paragraphs...